# Minimize and Uglify not working in Ionic2

Tags: ionic2, uglifyjs, minimized

I'm trying this, I set up alwaysRun to true in cordova-uglify and ionic-minify folders, but the only way to see the files minimized and uglified is running ionic  build android --release (but i don't want to generate the app for PRD yet)

If I do 
`ionic build android --minimize`
The result is the full file, not minimized.

Any idea how to get the files minimized? I'm trying to fix a performance issue with this as the app takes 12 seconds to open and in all sites suggest this as a performance improvement.

Comment: ionic build android --prod is what you want I think

Comment: But I can use that to test? I mean, with --release the code was minified, but as I don't have the certificates, I cannot install the app in a device

Comment: --prod just compiles it for production and lets you install it on device without certificates.

Comment: --prod will enable the Android just in time compiler, it's not the non-minification.